# Assigning to document.location.href without clobbering history

Tags: javascript

In testing document.location.href, I have observed that when the user initiates an action that results in javascript that assigns to document.location.href, the new URL is added to the history.

However, if the call is initiated by javascript that is result of, say, state change of an XMLHTTPRequest, the entry for the current page in the history is over-written. Have I characterized this correctly? Is there a way to get the page change to be reflected in the history in this latter case?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do. Do you want to remove the click-items from the history, or do you want to push the non-click address changes to the history?

Comment: Second one - I want my server to be able to tell the client to navigate to a new page -- preserving history -- as the result of a response to an XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was facing the same problem and found this workaround which worked for me

instead of

```
function onAjaxCallback(evt){
    location.href=newLocation;
}
```

i wrapped the location.href call around a setTimeout. Seems to do the trick. My history's behaving fine now. Hope that helps

```
function onAjaxCallback(evt){
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.href=newLocation;
    },0)
}
```

Comment: btw tested on chrome, ff3.5 and ie8

Comment: +1 this solved my problem over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629285/how-to-use-jquery-click-event-to-change-href-value-asyncronously-based-on-a-json

Answer (score 10):

You could change the location without having the browser display a Back button like this:

```
window.location.replace(new_url);
```

However, the original address remains in the browser's history and may be accessed using something like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#replace
- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.history#Notes

Answer (score 3):

study: `window.location.replace()` and `window.location.assign()`

Answer (score 2):

URL can be manually added to history before redirecting the user.

```
if (window.history) {
    history.pushState({}, window.location.href);
}
window.location.replace("/login/?next=" + window.location.pathname);
```

Comment: `window.location.replace` replaces the current history item so you can't go back to it. `pushState` is not needed if `window.location=...` is used.

Answer (score 1):

Read the original question more carefully. The question is not about content loaded by an XHR, but about content *loaded by a script* loaded by an XHR. I had the same problem and the setTimeout method seems to work well.

Answer (score -1):

Alas, your question can't be answered, AJAX requests have nothing to do with browser history, and if you loaded some dynamic content with them, then the user clicked the browser back button, the *previous* page is loaded (this which was loaded with an ordinary GET or POST request), which corrupts the sequence you display content in.

Dmitri's answers means that you will maintain your own history for the dynamic content using the fragment part of the url (this after the # symbol), maybe you'll provide your own back and forward buttons, but still you're not protected from the effect of the browser back and forward buttons.

If only they had provided some kind of events to handle user clicks on these buttons with the ability to cancel.