# How to use jQuery click event to change href value asynchronously, based on a JSON query

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, href, bit.ly

I'm using the [bit.ly url shortening service](https://bit.ly) to shorten certain url's being sent to a "share on twitter" function. I'd like to load the bit.ly url only when a user actually presses the share button (due to bit.ly's max 5 parallel reqs limitation). [Bit.ly's REST API](https://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation) returns a JSON callback with the shortened url, which makes the whole scenario async.

I've tried the following to stop the click event, and wait for the JSON call to return a value before launching the click.

I have the following simplified code in jQuery(document).ready():

**Updated code (oversimplified)!**

```
jQuery("#idofaelement").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //stop the click action
    var link = jQuery(this);
    bitlyJSON(function(shortUrl) {
        link.attr("href", function() {
          //process shortUrl
          //return finalized url;                   
        }).unbind().click();
    });
});
```

And the following code to handle the bitly shortening (works just fine):

```
function bitlyJSON(func) {
//
// build apiUrl here
//
jQuery.getJSON(apiUrl, function(data) {
    jQuery.each(data, function(i, entry) {
        if (i == "errorCode") {
            if (entry != "0") {
                func(longUrl);}
        } else if (i == "results") {
            func(entry[longUrl].shortUrl);}
    });
});  
} (jQuery)
```

The href gets its value changed, but the final .click() event never gets fired. This works fine when defining a static value for the href, but not when using the async JSON method.

Comment: can you please provide here the case that does work for you (the static value one)?

Comment: staic value used for testing: jQuery("#idofaelement").click(function(event) {link.attr("href", "http://urlhere");});

Comment: Is anything in `//process shortUrl` this async?

Comment: Nope. just collects values and builds up the twitter url. If i replace the function and use the returned json url directly i still get the same problem: ie: ...link.attr("href", shortUrl).unbind().click();...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Tzury Bar Yochay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9296/tzury-bar-yochay) pointed me in the right direction by suggesting I use location.href to update the url. Also [@Victor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14514/victor) helped with his answer.

I got things kinda working combining the answers, but had issues with the history in firefox. Seems that updating [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) indeed redirected the user, but also removed the "source page" from the history. This did **not** happen in chrome, safari, ie8, ie8-compatibility or ie7.

Based on [this response to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864633/assigning-to-document-location-href-without-clobbering-history/1439708#1439708) I was able to create a workaround giving the following working code + made a few changes:

```
jQuery("#idofaelement").one("click", function(event) {
    bitlyJSON(function(shortUrl) {
        jQuery("#idofaelement").attr("href", function() {
            //process shortUrl
            //return finalized url;                   
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location = jQuery("#idofaelement").attr("href");
        }, 0);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 5):

As you outlined yourself:

```
event.preventDefault(); //stop the click action
```

That means, **BROWSER IS NOT GOING TO THAT URL**, if you wish to actually go forward to the long-url location, simply do something like:

```
document.location.href = longurl;
```

Comment: as I mentioned to @stereofrog updating the location.href does cause a correct redirect. However, when clicking back in the browser, the user skips the page that initiated the click (seemingly back 2 slots). Which isnt desireable

Comment: sorry did not notice that. so may you try to use jQuery's trigger right after the long-url arrival. But that would require and if condition within the handler. That is, if href is of short-url - get the long one and prevent defaults, otherwise, do nothing, and let the browser treat it as standard link click

Comment: regarding location.href: could this be a FF issue? this functionality works fine in IE8 and chrome, from what I've tested

Comment: Another problem with this approach is that Ctrl+click (which would open a new tab) doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

iirc, jquery doesn't trigger "click" on A elements. I'd try old good "location.href=whatever" in the callback.

```
 bitlyJSON(function(shortUrl) {
      link.attr("href", function() {
      //process shortUrl
      //return finalized url;                   
    });
    location.href = link.attr("href");
});
```

Comment: Now this actually works. Didn't think of that. On a negative note though, when pressing "back" in the browser, it doesn't go to the page that actually launched the url.

Comment: could this be a FF issue? this functionality works fine in IE8 and chrome, from what I've tested

Answer (score 1):

I think what you actually want is to `return false;` from the click event, to prevent the actual following of the href, right?

Like:

```
jQuery("#idofaelement").click(function(event) {
    //event.preventDefault(); //stop the click action
    var link = jQuery(this);
    bitlyJSON(function(shortUrl) {
        link.attr("href", function() {
        //process shortUrl
        //return finalized url;                   
        }).unbind().click();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thx, but no luck here. Same end result. link opening gets stopped, and href gets updated