# How does Google change the urls in search result page

Tags: html, anchor

If you search something in Google (e.g. StackOverFlow), in search result page you can see the StackOverFlow item as result.

When you hover mouse in StackOverFlow item browser shows that it's an anchor element refers to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) . But when you right click on the item and click on `copy link address` the url is [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&ei=FsaZUZyeDcW1PefygdAE&usg=AFQjCNERidL9Hb6OvGW93_Y6MRj3aTdMVA&sig2=OvPhK-3c94CN-ugl5lH_Cg&bvm=bv.46751780,d.ZWU) .

How does Google do it?

Comment: The URL you get is redirection URL

Comment: I think they send you to StackOverflow to make some statistics.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I know that it redirect you to stackoverflow. but google use it for analytics or other things

Comment: @GustafRosenblad I know. I said `When you hover mouse in StackOverFlow item browser shows that it's an anchor element refers to stackoverflow.com . But when you right click on the item and click on copy link address the url is this.` I wanna know how google changes the href link.

Comment: i think it is simply done with JS. for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629285/how-to-use-jquery-click-event-to-change-href-value-asyncronously-based-on-a-jso

Comment: @fsw if it was simple js then `Copy link address` should copy the site url instead of `google.com/url` url!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/ works on left and right click. please note that if you hover on element it has the "right" url and after right click it gets changed to googly one. so change href on mouseover. also seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813648/how-do-google-and-yahoo-replace-the-url-in-the-browser-status-bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a id="changeMe" href="http://foo.com">click me</a>
```

as mentioned in comments guess this is as simple as:

```
$('#changeMe').mousedown(function(){
  $(this).attr('href', "http://bar.com")  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jpkL6/