# Edit query string of browser with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a requirement to edit the query string value in browser's address bar. 
example: Suppose we have a website www.domainname.com/default.aspx?id=abc.

There are links on page default.aspx named as abc, xyz and pqr. I want if user click on xyz then url should be www.domainname.com/default.aspx?id=xyz. (no server hit), it should be on client end only, no page allowed here. Same for pqr it should be www.domainname.com/default.aspx?id=pqr.

In contrast I want to edit and update query string values via JavaScript in browser's address bar. Is it possible please suggest?

Comment: You should probably use the hash string, not the query string, if no server-side code is involved. See [location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

Comment: your question is still not clear for me. you have links like <a href="xyz">xyz</a> or like .... href="xyz.aspx" ... ? and if you change urls as you would like, then the page will be "hit" requested server side, otherwise use hash tag

Comment: HTML5 History API, learn about it.

Comment: If you every time want to reload cached CSS files, See this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files#119056

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning to document.location.href without clobbering history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864633/assigning-to-document-location-href-without-clobbering-history)

Comment: server code is also involved in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern browsers support [HTML History pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries)

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

If you need older browser support, than you are out of luck and have to go the hash route.

Comment: No it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: WHAT is your problem? Do you not know how to listen for a click event,  call a function that calls pushState, and cancel the click event?

Comment: i know that but what about old browsers, and I think pushstate is working with html5 only.

Comment: Well it is impossible in older browsers because there was no way of doing it, hence my comment in my post: "*and have to go the hash route.*" There are libraries that fill that gap.