# History not recorded for navigation triggered by non-user-initiated action

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

My question is essentially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864633/assigning-to-document-location-href-without-clobbering-history), but now that 6 years have passed, it seems that the answer there doesn't work for today's browsers.

I have implemented Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce tracking, with code very similar to [this snippet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce?hl=en#product-click). That snippet assigns a new URL to document.location inside the hitCallback function (which is called asynchronously).

The problem is that after the user gets to the new page, their browser history doesn't include the previous page, instead if they click "back" they will go back two pages.

I am seeing this problem in Chrome and IE9. I'm not seeing it in Firefox.

I have tried the [workaround of using setTimeout in the callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1439708/602716) but it makes no difference in Chrome.

Here is the code in question:

```
     $(document).on('click', 'a.product', function() {
          ga('ec:addProduct', {
            'id': $(this).data('ean'),
            // a few more values, omitted for brevity
          });
         ga('ec:setAction', 'click', {list: 'Search results'});
         var href = $(this).attr('href');

         // Send click with an event, then send user to product page.
         ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'Results', {
              hitCallback: function() {
                document.location = href; // this line is the problem
              }
         });
         return false;
     });
```

**Edit:**
My page has lots of large images, and I just discovered that this problem only happens when a user clicks a product before all the images have finished loading.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DaImTo no, this is a javascript question, about how javascript (in this case, google-analytics code) affects browser history.

Comment: Sorry I am not seeing any javaScript looked like a generic Google Analytics setup question.    @davidwebster48 please post the code you are having a problem with if there is an issue with code.

Comment: I agree with Crayon Violent's interpretation - this is not a Google Analytics issue, it is a Javascript issue. I have added my code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this problem only happens when a user clicks a product before all the images have finished loading. So I made the images get lazy loaded, and this should greatly reduce the chance of a customer having this problem.